# Liquibase : build where clause with java

Tags: java, liquibase

I want to execute an update on a row using Liquibase but how can I set where param ? i can find the setter but I don't know what to put in it ? where id=value

```
UpdateDataChange updateDataChange=new UpdateDataChange();
columnConfig = new LoadDataColumnConfig();
columnConfig.setName(targetFieldKey);
columnConfig.setType("String");
columnConfig.setValue(value);
updateDataChange.addColumn(columnConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you put a condition in the where clause which makes the row(s) you want to update unique.

If you want to update one row, the most obvious choice would be to use the identifier of the table. Updating multiple rows could involve a condition with a `LIKE`.
For example: `WHERE name LIKE "%test%"`, would update all the rows where the name contain *test*.

It always depends on the use-case.